# Is there any chance a instance of a class (regular ctor) will be created before the static ctor completes it's run (in a multi-threaded environment)?

Tags: c#, constructor, static-constructor

I have a static ctor that fetches a configuration from my configuration server and sets a static variable.

I have a regular ctor that instantiates some properties based on that configuration.

Here's an example of my class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private static MyConfig _config;
   private UnitOfWork _uow;

   static MyClass(){
        // This takes some time since it's a web service call!!!
        _config = ConfigService.GetConfig(); 
   }

   public MyClass(){
        _uow = CreateUow(_config.UOWConnectionString);
   }

   public Response DoSomething(){
       // logic with _uow
   }
}
```

Assuming I have a *WCF* service that receives multiple requests, each request instantiates `MyClass` and runs the `DoSomething` method.

The static ctor performs a web service call that takes some time until it gets the result.

Can I be sure that the static ctor will finish running before **any request** will receive an instance of `MyClass`?

I know that static ctors are thread safe.

Is there any lock on creating new instances until the static ctor completes to run?

Comment: It will be called _before_ any instance is created, so yes you can be sure. However I hope you understand how bad is it to call _web service_ from static constructor.

Comment: I hate to undermine your design, but having a static constructor call an external service that takes time (and can, by definition: fail) seems like a *really* bad idea to me.

Comment: @MarcGravell Evk - Thanks for the answer.

I understand that the design isn't the best practice and I'm looking for a better solution.

Assuming you have a service that fetches it's configuration from a config server, whats the best approach on fetching the config prior to instantiating the class? 

I have some properties that need the configuration and need to be instantiated on every request (e.g. the unit of work).

Thanks.

Comment: You need to perform lazy initialization of your configuration then. That is - whenever you need your configuration (in your example above that is in instance constructor) - check if configuration is loaded, and if not - load it. Of course you need to do that in a thread safe manner, easiest way to achieve that is to use Lazy class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Evk - Thanks for the response. I've thought about the Lazy + thread safety way as well and I think that you convinced me about changing the static ctor to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static constructors are guaranteed to be run before any instance is created. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class
>   before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced.

Comment: While factual, I don't feel this really addresses the concern raised in the question, i.e. - the instance constructor being called from another thread while the static constructor is already running.

Comment: @Rotem "before the first instance"